# Undefined offset: 2 ( php function )

Tags: php, html, mysql

So-.. I was looking up how to fix this function; but I can't seem to find out. Can anyone give a hand?
I get an error on this line ( I'll include the php function ).
PHP function:

```
while($sql_row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
```

Actual faulty line:

```
<tr>

    <td><a <?php echo 'href="character_staff.php?action=manage&name=' . $sql_row[0] . '"'; ?>><?php echo $sql_row[0]; ?></a></td>

    <td><a <?php echo 'href="character_staff.php?action=manage&name=' . $sql_row[0] . '"'; ?>><?php echo $sql_row[2]; ?></a></td>

</tr>
```

I can't seem to find out how to fix it. It has to change the URL into a link that contains text ( IE: character_staff.php?action=manage&name=account_name )

Comment: So what columns are being returned by your SQL query?

Comment: ID, Name - where ID is an ID given at registration ( AI ) and Name being the actual name that has to fit in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
<?php echo $sql_row[2]; ?>
```

Your code is attempting to echo the third element of the $sql_row array, but the array does not contain three elements. There are two ways to fix the problem: change the code to reference only elements that exist in the array, or change the array to contain more elements.

Note: in case you are wondering why `$sql_row[2]` looks for the third element, it is because arrays are zero-indexed.

```
$sql_row[0]
```

returns the first element.

```
$sql_row[1]
```

returns the second element, and so on.

Comment: This has the fix in it. I didn't kept this in mind, hence why it always tried to get one later. Thanks.